How are the two Bush presidents scored or ranked by Republicans?
I was fairly shocked by this poll:

Until I gave it a closer reading and realized it's asking about the "best" president, which forced people to choose just one. (BTW, Reagan was preferred by older Republicans, and Trump by the younger, under 49 y.o. The same split applies by completed college education vs not.)
So, I'm curious if there are similar polls where the responds were allowed to give scores or rank presidents, instead of just being asked who the "best" one was. How do the two Bush presidents score in such more forgiving setting, relative to Trump and Reagan?

It is just a poll asking people who they thought was the best president with a follow-up of who is the second best. We have no way of knowing how each person chose their ranking

@JoeW: which is precisely why I'm asking if there's a different kind of polling on this.

According to a Gallup approval poll, Republicans see the Bushes as...OK.  Lower approval than either Reagan or Trump, but higher than Nixon.


I don't know why Johnson (D) and Ford (R) were excluded from the poll.

Seems a strong correlation between high scores and being shot.
